# Trying to connect to api with link stored in two components

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to fetch data from API, using the link combined from link fetched from another component and API token, but the API is not returning anything.

I suspect the connection to API might be correct and the issue lies with wrongly fetching specific objects from the API structure. [api structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMagE.png)

```
componentDidMount(){    
const { navigation } = this.props;    
const linkPlant = navigation.getParam('linkPlant');    

fetch(linkPlant + '?token=/////FY03yEVzS77Ca1Q9TIbMdMlJhXtpOjhcqcD-MJHA')    
.then(response => response.json())    
.then((responseJson)=> {        
 this.setState({
  loading: false,
  dataSource: responseJson
 })
 })
 .catch(error=>console.log(error)) 
 }

 renderItem=(data)=>

 <TouchableOpacity style={styles.list}>
        <Text style={styles.lightText}>{data.item.varieties[0].common_name}</Text> 
 </TouchableOpacity>

 render(){

 return(

        <View> 
  <FlatList
     data= {this.state.dataSource}
     renderItem= {item=> this.renderItem(item)}
     keyExtractor= {item=>item.id.toString()} />
  </View>

</ScrollView>
 );}
```

Comment: did you tried to log dataSource to console? is that log something or just undefined?

Comment: console shows the whole api

Answer (score 0):

```
 {!loading?
  <View> 
  <FlatList
     data= {this.state.dataSource}
     renderItem= {item=> this.renderItem(item)}
     keyExtractor= {item=>item.id.toString()} />
  </View>
 : <View><Text>Loading</Text></View>}
```

You've defined an loading promise but never used that. Maybe using it for render when page is loaded could be fix that error.

Comment: I am sorry but that doesn't work for me. I suspect that I have problem with printing my data because API data I am fetching it is consisting of 1 object and not an array, and Flatlist has problem with rendering only one object but I can not change it so it will work.